# how to do unit tests in roles decorators nestJS?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, nestjs, decorator, ts-jest

I looked everywhere, but I couldn't find any documentation on how to create tests with nestjs decorators, and I couldn't find much on the site itself either.

can you help me?

```
import { SetMetadata } from '@nestjs/common'

export const Roles = (...args: string[]) => SetMetadata('roles', args)
```

Comment: I suggest you to read this: [Selective Unit Testing – Costs and Benefits](https://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/11/04/selective-unit-testing-costs-and-benefits/)

Answer (score 1):

Do you really nee a unit test for this? No seriously, a unit test should be there to ensure that your logic works as expected. Here, you're taking an array of strings an passing it to a method from the framework, no custom logic, no transformation, you're essentially just writing `@SetMetadata('roles', roles)`. Would you write a unit test for that decorator that you **didn't** write? The answer should be no, it was written by the framework/library the framework/library should test it instead. If you had custom logic to transform the data, that might be a different story, but this is pretty much just passing things straight on, I wouldn't test this at all.